# SQL Server filename extension

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to ask something about sql. When I export a database in MySQL to a file, that dump has `.sql` extention. How about SQL Server, can I also use the `.sql` extension, or should I use another extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `.sql` as the file extension is just a convention to indicate the file contains SQL statements, and it helps editors to apply SQL code highlighting.

It says nothing about the specific SQL dialect, so if you want to use `.sql` for SQL statements from MySQL and from SQL Server, you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) is just a loose standard for interacting databases. While the ISO specifications are quite specific, vendors often take a wildly different approach when it comes to implementing them. In effect there are dozens of different *dialects* of SQL, many of which have only a superficial similarity.

MySQL, SQLite, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase, PostgreSQL, etc, they all use `.sql` files in some form. There's no extension for "MySQL SQL" or "SQL Server SQL". Sometimes their database backups have a predictable extension, but usually that's arbitrary as well, like `.dump` or `.db`.